# Splitting up a controller and routing to controllers via 2 URL levels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a reports controller (ReportsController), that i've decided to split up as it contains too many actions.  I currently have three pages that the controller serves:

app/reports/settings/

app/reports/charts/

app/reports/tables/

I decided to use the ReportsController just for the settings page, and I have created two seperate controllers to handle the other pages - Reports__ChartsController & Reports__TablesController.

I added the following two routes to my routes config:

```
routes.Add(
            new Route("reports/charts/{action}/{id}",
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new { controller = "Reports__Charts", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
                new HyphenatedRouteHandler()
            )
        );

routes.Add(
            new Route("reports/tables/{action}/{id}",
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new { controller = "Reports__Tables", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
                new HyphenatedRouteHandler()
            )
        );
```

The approach works really well, but I was wondering if there is a better way?  The downside to this approach is that if I wanted to split out other controllers I would need to keep adding entries to my route config specific to each controller, which could enlarge my route config to the point where it's hard to maintain.

I assume what I wanted to do (splitting up controllers) is a common requirement, but i've not come across a standard method of implementing it via google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is exactly why we pounced on attribute based routing as soon as it was released. One route per action, in a clear concise manner, and moving actions between controllers is seamless, especially if you make use of the controller level attributes [RouteArea] and [RoutePrefix]. The sooner you make the switch, the happier you'll be. We've never looked back.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  The convention-based routing fits my needs for 90% of the app (default routing), so i'm glad I can stick with it and at the same time use attribute-based routing for the pages that don't fit an easy routing convention